# With bytebuddy is it possible to enhance a field that is annotated where the annotation has a specific attribute value?

Tags: java, byte-buddy

I'm trying to use bytebuddy to redefine existing classes.  I'm looking for fields that are annotated with a specific annotation.  I've got that figure out with code something like this:

```
new ByteBuddy()
        .redefine(<some class>)
        .field(
            ElementMatchers.isAnnotatedWith(<some annotation>)
        )
        ...
```

What I'd like to do is further refine my ElementMatcher to include a check for an attribute on the specified annotation - something like this:

```
new ByteBuddy()
        .redefine(<some class>)
        .field(
            ElementMatchers.isAnnotatedWith(<some annotation>)
                .havingAttribute(<some attribute>, "value")
        )
```

What I'm looking for is the way to do the "havingAttribute" part.  Is this possible or am I approaching this the wrong way?  Any insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

One approach would be to create a `Advice.OffsetMapping.Factory` which lets you inject the annotation value in your advice like this:

```
@Advice.OnMethodEnter(suppress = Throwable.class)
public static void onMethodEnter(@AnnotationValueExtractor(annotationClassName = "co.elastic.apm.api.CaptureSpan", method = "value") String spanName) {
    if (spanName.equals("foo")) {
        // do something special
    }
}
```

See also:
https://github.com/elastic/apm-agent-java/blob/f6781c3d740602f000332f9b4a5b5ecb0d01627a/apm-agent-core/src/main/java/co/elastic/apm/agent/bci/bytebuddy/AnnotationValueOffsetMappingFactory.java

Comment: I'm a complete beginner with ByteBuddy and not up to speed on the @Advice annotation. I'm not sure how I could put this to use to solve my particular problem.  Instead, what I ended up doing is implementing a custom ElementMatcher that looks for the specific annotation that I'm interested in, loads this annotation and then checks the attribute value on the loaded annotation.  Not sure if this would be the recommended approach but it worked.

Comment: Loading the annotation is typically fine. I would avoid the cast in your soltution, you can achieve this using Byte Buddy's API. If the underlying annotation is already from a loaded type, you basically just access it using the reflection API under the hoods.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up implementing a custom ElementMatcher like this:

```
public class NeedsLazyToOneNoProxy<T extends AnnotationSource> extends ElementMatcher.Junction.AbstractBase<T> {


    public boolean matches(T target) {
        AnnotationDescription oneToOneAnnotation = target.getDeclaredAnnotations().ofType(OneToOne.class);
        try {
            if (oneToOneAnnotation != null) {
                OneToOne oneToOne = (OneToOne) ((AnnotationDescription.Loadable) oneToOneAnnotation).load();
                FetchType fetchType = oneToOne.fetch();
                return fetchType == FetchType.LAZY;
            }
            return false;
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage(), e);
        }

    }
}
```

I use this element matcher to determine if I should add a @LazyToOne annotation to an existing @OneToOne relationship.